# MariaDB data separation in public and private, database design

Tags: sql, mariadb, sharding

I am working at a company that merged with another company a while ago.
There we have several business units that are basically equivalent. One in Europe, one in China, each. We already had an in-house MariaDB database, which we want to start sharing.

The problem is that there are different GDPR regulations and contracts that prohibit sharing certain data across sites. So what I can't do, is replicate data across sites and then just hide in from the user in the frontend. The private data has to stay at the facility, it belongs to.

So my idea was to separate each table that we have now and where possibly sensitive information is contained into two tables each.
One say table_contracts_private and table_contracts_public.

This would still seem pretty doable with basic database replication and replicating the public tables across sites. But how would you go about publishing private data? Also how would I best combine private and public data? Just using a view

I just could not find any good mechanisms for this, especially because we would also like to avoid data duplication, so the private entries would need to be removed and replaced by the public ones, which would entail also changing all referencing IDs.

Is this a possible application of sharding?

I'd be really grateful, if someone could point me in the right direction, or if someone has a demo project with similar requirements that I could check out.

Cheers

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to tag individual records public or privatem and only replicate the public ones. Is it as simple as that or can one record be allowed at three sites and another record only be allowed at one of those sites?

Comment: I can tell you in SQL Server, you can add a WHERE clause to replication and replicate a subset of rows. But you still have to deal with FK's. I really don't recommend creating seperate tables to manage this if you can avoid it, but that might be the only solution

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the input. You absolutely got the idea. But then how would you go about the FK situation? I just can't really wrap my head around a mechanism that would allow both sites to share entries, without causing conflicting or otherwise problematic FKs?

Comment: You could use data masking / obfuscation. Replicate all data. For data that is not allowed to be shared, overwrite all attributes with XXX. No FK problem then. However you will need to replicate a bunch of dummy data

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a possible application of sharding?

I wouldn't think so.  Sharding is a performance optimization method.  What you need is to support legal constraints.  Those are two very different problems.

I think you are on the right track.  I call this a "walled garden" approach.  You create a database with all non-PII information, using ids only.  Nothing that remotely directly identifies people, their addresses, phones, credit cards, and so on.  This can be tricky.  In some jurisdictions combinations of demographics can be PII.

Some of those ids then refer to *another* database where you store all the sensitive information; this is the "walled garden".  I would recommend that this second database be on a separate server.  It has a very restricted access list.  And this is where you implement requirements for things like "forgetting" a customer.

In any case, the point is that sharding is not the right approach.  You want an application redesign with privacy and security as the top priorities.  Happily, this is not actually that hard to implement, although if the databases are changing, you may need period auditing.  For instance, in one database I worked with, we discovered that "coupon codes" sometimes contained unencrypted email addresses.  Arrgggh!

Comment: Hello Gordon and thank you for your answer! Would you have any further reading on how I might implement such a "walled garden"? One of the issues would actually be that the database, or at least parts of it are still in active development, so yes, changes would occur. I only thought that sharding implements horizontal partitioning and kinda sounded like what I was looking for.

Comment: @n00by0815 . . . I don't know of good resources on this specific topic, alas.